# PHP SQL Table Titles Repeating

Tags: php, sql

The code works but the title is repeated with each new set of data. I want the titles set up at the top and never repeating... No idea what is causing it.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------randomtextrandomtextrandomtextrandomtextrandomtextrandomtextrandomtextrandomtextrandomtext-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT deadchar, level, class, killforumid, realm, date FROM pkdata ORDER BY deadchar DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


$deadchar = $row['deadchar'];
$level = $row['level'];
$class = $row['class'];
$killforumid = $row['killforumid'];
$realm = $row['realm'];
$date = $row['date'];

$conn->close();

    echo
        "<table><center><tr>

            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

           <font size=3 color=#070719>Victim</font>

           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <font size=3 color=#070719>Level</font>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

           <font size=3 color=#070719>Class</font>

           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

           <font size=3 color=#070719>Killer</font>

           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

           <font size=3 color=#070719>Realm</font>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <font size=3 color=#070719>Date</font>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>

            </tr></center>";




        echo
            "<tr><center>

            <td><center>$deadchar</center></td>
            <td><center>$level</center></td>
            <td><center>$class</center></td>
            <td><center>$killforumid</center></td>            
            <td><center>$realm</center></td>
            <td><center>$date</center></td>           

            </tr>";

    echo "</table>";




}

?>
```

Comment: You should look into CSS to do spacing and assign styles. Look at my example as it will get you what you want.

Comment: @les and I have both provided you with working examples, he leaves the `&nbsp` in his example. I chose to change your `<th>` so that it is a lot neater and easier to read. The `style='text-align:center'` will work as your `<center>` so that the text of your headings are in the center. You might also want to consider giving your `<th>`s and `<td>`s a certain width

Comment: You should **never** echo HTML tags, since PHP itself a template engine. Use alternate tags, like `if/endif`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is extremely messy.

You should never use

```
&nbsp;
```

to layout your code.

Now to your problem, your titles are repeating because you have them inside your while() loop, therefore for each piece of data it will create the title again.

```
    echo
        "<table><tr>

            <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#070719>Victim</font></th>
            <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#070719>Level</font></th>
            <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#070719>Class</font></th>
            <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#070719>Killer</font></th>
            <th style='text-align:center'> <font size=3 color=#070719>Realm</font></th>
            <th style='text-align:center'><font size=3 color=#070719>Date</font></th>

            </tr>";





$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT deadchar, level, class, killforumid, realm, date FROM pkdata ORDER BY deadchar DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


$deadchar = $row['deadchar'];
$level = $row['level'];
$class = $row['class'];
$killforumid = $row['killforumid'];
$realm = $row['realm'];
$date = $row['date'];
        echo
            "<tr>

            <td style='text-align:center'>".$deadchar."</td>
            <td style='text-align:center'>".$level."</td>
            <td style='text-align:center'>".$class."</td>
            <td style='text-align:center'>".$killforumid."</td>            
            <td style='text-align:center'>".$realm."</td>
            <td style='text-align:center'>".$date."</td>           

            </tr>";

}

echo "</table>";


$conn->close();


?>
```

try this, it'll work

Answer (score 0):

Remove the table titles from within your loop. Put them above the loop and this will not happen. Be sure and put the `</table>` outside/after the loop.

EDIT:

```
<?php
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  $sql = "SELECT deadchar, level, class, killforumid, realm, date FROM pkdata ORDER BY deadchar DESC";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  // initialize your variable (not needed, but okay to do at the top to keep things organized if you have multiple variables at play.)
  $myTable = '';

  // the ".=" appends to a variable once it is initialized already
  $myTable .= 
    '<table>
        <tr>
          <th>Victim</th>
          <th>Level></th>
          <th>Class</th>
          <th>Killer</th>
          <th>Realm</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>';

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $deadchar = $row['deadchar'];
    $level = $row['level'];
    $class = $row['class'];
    $killforumid = $row['killforumid'];
    $realm = $row['realm'];
    $date = $row['date'];

    $myTable .= '
        <tr>
          <td>'.$deadchar.'</td>
          <td>'.$level.'</td>
          <td>'.$class.'</td>
          <td>'.$killforumid.'</td>            
          <td>'.$realm.'</td>
          <td>'.$date.'</td>           
        </tr>';
  }
  $myTable .= '</table>';
  $conn->close();
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  /* Here is where you enter your styles instead of in your PHP */
  table {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
  th, td {
    font-size:3; 
    color:#070719
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This will echo out your table -->
  <?php echo $myTable; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't hesitate either to remove your `$conn->close();` from the loop, closing it once should be enough...

Comment: @fpierrat good point. Also look into CSS as it will help clean your code and allow you to focus on programming errors instead of styling.